# Is SparkSQL RDBMS or NOSQL?

Tags: sql, hive, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, nosql

Recently, I was having a discussion with my friend over the features of SparkSQL when we came across this question. Are they ACID transactions? Does SparkSQL follow CAP theorem?

I am a little new to this field, help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SparkSQL is a query language and not a storage like Hive or MYSQL. Although it can register table which can be used by others, its only temporary. SparkSQL supports what the underlying databases support.

Answer (score 3):

SparkSQL follows the Relational database model. 
It does not support Hive transactions ("ACID").

Following are few useful posts:

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_rn_spark_ki.html
http://db-engines.com/en/system/Oracle+NoSQL%3BSAP+IQ%3BSpark+SQL