# Spark and Cassandra: Recommended way to interface

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have been using the [DataStax Cassandra Java driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) from Spark driver to insert data to Cassandra tables. It seems that [Spark SQL](http://spark.apache.org/sql/) can also be used for the same. Though for a NoSQL DB like Cassandra, it seems to be wrong to misuse the [JOIN operation](http://www.datastax.com/2015/03/how-to-do-joins-in-apache-cassandra-and-datastax-enterprise) that is supported in Spark SQL, for NoSQL data modeling done in Cassandra.

From what I have understood, I would rather stick with Cassandra Java driver. However want to know if I have missed something in this.

Which is more efficient to use or better recommended to use with Cassandra.

Related question - [Is SparkSQL RDBMS or NOSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142172/is-sparksql-rdbms-or-nosql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the most popular way to work with Cassandra from a Spark app is using `Spark Cassandra Connector`: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

Comment: I am using the above to read in the data from Cassandra in a distributed manner. For writing I am preparing the CQL statements and using com.datastax.driver.core.Session .executeAsync - from the datastax java driver